# JS time difference in event triggering by click and keypress

Tags: javascript

I am building a beats-per-minute(BPM) calculator in JavaScript that can be triggered by both click and keypress. When using only keyboard or only mouse/touchpad, it works fine. However, if I start tapping with my mouse and then continue with keyboard at the same pace, the resulting BPM value jumps up by 10% or more; if I start tapping with keyboard and continue with mouse, it drops down. It then normalizes after 4 taps in booth cases, which makes me think that the problem is related to switching between input methods: [CodePen](https://codepen.io/tssss/pen/abNzmoz)

```js
const body = document.querySelector("body"),
      tappingButton = document.getElementById("tapping-button"),
      result = document.getElementById("result");

var tapTime = [],
    firstTap = true;

function calculator() {    
    let addTap;
    let removeTap;
  
      //Skips calculation until there are at least 2 taps:
    if (firstTap === true) {
        firstTap = false;
        addTap = tapTime.unshift(Date.now());
        result.innerHTML = "0";
    } else {
      
    //Calculates average bpm based on last <= 4 taps:
      addTap = tapTime.unshift(Date.now());
      if (tapTime.length > 4) {
              removeTap = tapTime.pop();
      }
      let averageBPM = Math.round ((tapTime.length - 1) / (tapTime[0] - tapTime[tapTime.length - 1]) * 60000);

  result.innerHTML = averageBPM;
  }
}

//Event listeners:
tappingButton.addEventListener("click", calculator, false);
body.addEventListener("keypress", calculator, false);
```

```html
<body>
  <p>Click on the button or press any key to define BPM</p>
  <div id = "tapping-button" 
    style = "width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      background-color: green;
      box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px grey;">
  </div>
  <p>Your BPM: </p><p id = "result"></p>
</body>
```

I've tried targeting different elements with the event listener; it doesn't seem to make any difference.

Any idea about what is causng different behaviour at switching and how to make it consistent?

Comment: What happens when you try `document.addEventListener("keyup", calculator, false);`? So applying to `document` and using `keyup` not `keypress`?

Comment: @imvain2 tried that, as well as `keydown` and `mousedown` - didn't solve the problem.